# Magento 2 - Data Migration Tool - Triggers

Tags: magento2, data-migration, data-migration-tool, eav-attributes, magento2.3.5

## Intro

Regarding the **Data Migration Tool (M1 to M2)**, the migration creates `m2_cl_` trigger tables that I can eventually run `bin/magento migrate:delta` will **only update those triggered tables, or do they update `eav_attribute` items as well**?

The main question is: for all the other tables that *do not have `m2_cl_`* triggers setup, can I simply just copy them after delta migration completes?

## Discussion

For instance, **none of the `eav_attribute` tables** have `m2_cl_` trigger tables in the source database.

I have migration that is not really working completely, **products out of stock (other related question)**, attributes not all being imported into their corresponding `eav_attribute_group` tables (especially 50% of the configurable attribute groups for some reason.

I am tired of trying to solve the migration the way I have been doing - I have around 15 steps which data processed after initial migration `(migrate:data)` finishes to get categories, etc working.  These remaining issues with attributes, groups, and attribute sets that do not import correctly are a major headache.

Quite simply, the *Data Migration Tool* does not work 100%, especially not with our data that have over 300 attributes, 30 configurables etc.   I would simply just want to be able to import the required tables afterwards.

### Question:

So, the main question is: for all the other tables that *do not have `m2_cl_`* triggers setup, can I simply just copy them after delta migration completes?  (I will just want to concentrate on the `eav_attribute` entries firstly).

Comment: Good morning, does anyone have any advice on this please? Thank you :)